# FreeBSD major update broke vpnc connectivity, incoming ESP traffic doesn't appear unencrypted on interfaces

Tags: freebsd, ipsec, cisco-vpn, vpn-client

I updated a `FreeBSD` box from `10.4` to `11.2-RELEASE-p4` recently and it seems to have broken the `vpnc` VPN connectivity.

Here's the `vpnc.conf`:

```
IPSec gateway 10.1.0.1
IPSec ID vpnuser
IPSec secret su0hoh8liNgeiT8
Xauth username vpnuser
Xauth password miuthei3Niew2ee
Nat Traversal Mode none
Noninteractive
```

Following the interface configuration; em0 is the hardware interface with private IP address, tun0 the vpnc's interface with a public address.

```
em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
  options=209b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,WOL_MAGIC>
  inet 10.2.2.1 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 10.2.3.255
  nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
  media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
  status: active
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
  options=600003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
  inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
  inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2
  inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
  nd6 options=21
  groups: lo
tun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1412
  options=80000<LINKSTATE>
  inet x.11.11.60 --> x.11.11.60 netmask 0xffffffff
  nd6 options=29
  groups: tun
  Opened by PID 90343
```

So far I've found out:

- vpnc can apparently get the VPN connection up, running vpnc with `--no-detach` doesn't show any critical errors. I am using the same config as before with the previous `FreeBSD` version where it worked flawlessly. I've also tried a few versions of `vpnc-scripts`. I've also tested it with pf firewall rules flushed with `pfctl -F all`.
- pings sent from the local machine (`ping 8.8.8.8`) do show in `tcpdump -ni tun0` as outgoing traffic:

  ```
  00:58:24.017976 IP x.11.11.60 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 42593, seq 4, length 64
  ```
- pings sent from the local machine show in `tcpdump -ni em0`; interesting is that the VPN packet seems to get a proper response each time and the response reaches the hardware interface of local machine:

  ```
  00:58:24.018029 IP 10.2.2.1 > 10.1.0.1: ESP(spi=0x1bcc60be,seq=0x3c), length 132
  00:58:24.078558 IP 10.1.0.1 > 10.2.2.1: ESP(spi=0xe48f7620,seq=0x6b), length 132
  ```
- however, the returning packet doesn't show up in `tcpdump`.
- ping packets from a random external (internet) host to x.11.11.60 do induce similar traffic which can be seen on `em0` but not on `tun0`:

  ```
  01:35:32.612015 IP 10.1.0.1 > 10.2.2.1: ESP(spi=0xe48f7620,seq=0x124), length 132
  ```

Changing `sysctl` value of `net.inet.ip.forwarding` doesn't seem to have any effect.

VPN (tun0) should be the host's default route out. Based on the finding that the example ping gets a response back til `em0` this doesn't seem to be a routing problem.

Can you spot something I'm missing? Any ideas how could I get the VPN connection working again?

---

UPDATE – New findings:

It now seems probable that this is not a `vpnc` specific problem. Rather there might be something with ESP handling on `FreeBSD 11`.

- I found a workaround to the problem which is simply to force the NAT traversal mode with `--natt-mode force-natt` despite there's no NAT between the hosts. For some reason there's no problem with encapsulated UDP:

What shows on `em0`...

```
14:15:18.500251 IP 10.2.2.1.4500 > 10.1.0.1.4500: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0x66842bb7,seq=0x3), length 132
14:15:18.527137 IP 10.1.0.1.4500 > 10.2.2.1.4500: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0x3a4661f0,seq=0x3), length 132
```

... can be seen unencrypted now also on `tun0`:

```
14:15:18.500200 IP x.11.11.60 > 172.217.21.142: ICMP echo request, id 64016, seq 2, length 64
14:15:18.527188 IP 172.217.21.142 > x.11.11.60: ICMP echo reply, id 64016, seq 2, length 64
```

- I set up a separate solution with `racoon` using [FreeBSD manual](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ipsec.html) and it showed similar behaviour when it comes to apparently not handling incoming ESP packets. For some reason I get now the error `vpnc[3372]: esp sendto: Invalid argument` when I try to ping if `vpnc` was started with `--natt-mode none`.
- It seems there has been some changes to IPsec, ESP, and NAT-T in `FreeBSD` [11.0R](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/11.0R/relnotes.html) and [11.1R](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/11.1R/relnotes.html). Maybe those changes interfere with something now.

Any help is still appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you went directly to 11.2p4 from 10.0? I've always read that's a bad idea to make such a major jump in one step.

Comment: Thanks for asking. The upgrade was from the last (or one of the latest) production version of 10.4 but just now I can't remember the point release. To me anything doesn't look like there had been problems with the upgrade process itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I upgraded to latest version of 11 in one shot so now I can't know if something between the releases of 11 made something break.